# Magento: Two flat rate Shipping Rates based on weight

Tags: magento

Trying to set up my shipping rates as follows:

If the total shopping cart is under 1KG in weight then the shipping will be £3.68

If the total shopping cart is over 1KG in weight then the shipping will be £6.68

If the total price of the cart is over £100 shipping is free.

I’ve managed to hack this all together using a flat rate of £6.68 then using the Promotions > Shopping cart price rules section to discount the extra £3 if under the 1KG weight. But the deduction doesn’t come off the shipping price, it simply displays as a discount which will be confusing and doesn’t look right. So i’m looking for a alternative/the right way.

All this is in the UK, we don’t ship abroad for the moment.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use table rates.

In the menu System > Configuration > Shipping Methods, change the "Current Configuration Scope" to a website then an Export button will become available in the Table Rates section. The condition should be "Weight vs. Destination" to get the right file. Download the exported file and modify it to something like this;

```
Country  Region/State  Zip/Postal Code  Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
UK       *             *                0                   3.68
UK       *             *                1                   6.68
```

You might need to play with the values, I am unsure of the units of weight. Import to the same part of configuration.

Use a shopping cart price rule to apply the free shipping. There is a "Free Shipping" action specifically for this.

Comment: hi.. It dint work for me. I m using version 1.7.0.2. Importing and Exporting Process looks good (I have used No of items instead of weight) but the shipping price doesnt get updated in the checkout page. Any Help Pls...

Comment: Welcome to SO, itdeeps.  Perhaps your problem is worthy of a question all to itself.  That way you can go into more detail, paste an extract of the CSV file you made, etc...

Comment: Sorry I got it to work.. Problem is with country code in excel.. I have tried with 2 letters country code it dint work but when i tried with 3 letters country code it worked. Thanks anyway..If you dont mind you can help me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264084/magento-downloadable-products-always-empty . Unable to fix it :(

Comment: Your answer saved a-lot of efforts and time

Comment: what happens if weight is in decimal .

Comment: @AmiteshKumar have you tried it? I think decimal weights will work too.

Comment: yes decimal is working  but if weight is 0.9 the price will be 3.68 but i want 6.68