# Custom shipping in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a website in Magento. It is working fine, but I want to define custom shipping.

For example:

- I have two types of product: A and B.
- If the user selects A, then shipping will be $5 to the US, and $8 elsewhere.
- If the user selects one A and one B, then shipping will be $5 to the US, and 8 elsewhere.
- If the user selects one A and one B then shipping will be $4 to the US, and $7 elsewhere.

I have taken help from this article, but I need to modify this:

[Magento: Two flat rate Shipping Rates based on weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032884/magento-two-flat-rate-shipping-rates-based-on-weight)

Comment: I tried to fix up your question, but there appears to be a typo in one of your use cases. Can you correct your meaning there? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: We really need that Magento SE site to get going, as this is not a programming question and should not be on SO at all

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of achieving this, but you are on the right track with that article.  The trick is pulling in all the data you need to make the calculations.  I would likely just get a cheap plugin that handles this for you.  This will do the trick in letting you create custom rates based on combinations of product, destination, price, weight, etc.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/17930/